# How to copy entire row based on Percentage comparison of 2 Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy an entire row to another sheet if a cell is greater than 2% of another cell in the same row. This is what I'm stuck, getting an IF Greater based off a formula comparing 2 cells:

```
Sub Filtration()

For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("R:R")
    If Formula = "(R1 / P1)" > 0.021 Then
        matchRow = Cell.Row
        Rows(matchRow & ":" & matchRow).Select
        Selection.Copy

        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Rows(matchRow).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    End If
Next
```

EDIT: Thanks to @JNevil & @ShaiRado and the help they provide, I think I'm only stuck on the Macro returning an Overflow. I think that the `percentage = Cell.Value / Cell.Offset(, -2).Value` is being confused/conflicted some how and believes that `percentage = 0` always. There is also the issue that my `Sheet1` contains blank lines, a header, and possible negative numbers on future updates. The full code is as follows:

```
Sub Filtration()

Dim writeRow As Integer
Dim percentage As Double

For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("R:R")

    'because we don't want to do this for every cell in Column R (There are one million), then exit the loop when we need to
    If Cell.Value = "" Or Cell.Value <= 0 Then

    'Lets make sure we won't be dividing by zero. If we are then set the result to 0
    If Cell.Offset(, -2).Value < 0 Then
        percentage = 0
    Else

        percentage = Cell.Value / Cell.Offset(, -2).Value

    End If

    'divide the current cell's value by the the cell one column over's value and compare
    If percentage > 0.021 Then

        'Write this out to the writeRow variable in the other sheet and increment that number by 1 after writing
        Sheet1.Rows(Cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 1).Paste
        writeRow = writeRow + 1
    End If
    End If
Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Where is what you are stuck?

Comment: I'm currently not knowledge enough to figure out how to get excel vba to do the IF greater than based off a formula. I'm sorry that I forgot that in the question, I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 2):

For having only been writing VBA for a week, you are doing a pretty good job here. Most people avoid For loops like the plague when they are learning.

A couple of things.

1. Avoid `.select` that is a user interface thing. VBA doesn't need to "Select" anything. You just point it at a range or a cell or a object and do what you need it to do.
2. Avoid `activesheet` and `activeworkbook`. When you are a couple hundred lines of code down don't risk assuming that you know what will be the active sheet or active workbook at that point in time. Don't trust it. Be explicit `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("mysheetname")` or similar.
3. Do the math in VBA. Don't call `formula` or whatever. VBA is good at it.

Something like the following should get you in the ballpark:

```
Sub Filtration()

    For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("R:R")
        'divide the current cell's value by the the cell one column over's value and compare
        If cell.value/cell.offset(,-2).value > .021 Then
            Sheet1.Rows(cell.row).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(cell.row, 1)           
            'because we don't want to do this for every cell in Column R (There are one million), then exit the loop when we need to
            If cell.value = "" Then Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

You may want to write to the other sheet without jumping rows. In that case you can employ a variable to track which row to write to:

```
Sub Filtration()
    Dim writeRow as integer

    For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("R:R")

        'because we don't want to do this for every cell in Column R (There are one million), then exit the loop when we need to
        If cell.value = "" Then Exit For

        'divide the current cell's value by the the cell one column over's value and compare
        If cell.value/cell.offset(,-2).value > .021 Then

            'Write this out to the writeRow variable in the other sheet and increment that number by 1 after writing
            Sheet1.Rows(cell.row).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 1)    
            writeRow = writeRow + 1             

        End If
    Next
```

Because dividing by zero will cause this code to fail, it may be a good idea to do your division before you check the result in the `if` statement. You can use a variable to capture the value for later comparison:

```
Sub Filtration()
    Dim writeRow as integer
    Dim percentage as double

    For Each Cell In Sheets(1).Range("R:R")

        'because we don't want to do this for every cell in Column R (There are one million), then exit the loop when we need to
        If cell.value = "" Then Exit For

        'Lets make sure we won't be dividing by zero. If we are then set the result to 0
        if cell.offset(,-2).value = 0 Then
            percentage = 0
        else
            percentage=cell.value/cell.offset(,-2).value
        end if

        'divide the current cell's value by the the cell one column over's value and compare
        If  percentage > .021 Then

            'Write this out to the writeRow variable in the other sheet and increment that number by 1 after writing
            Sheet1.Rows(cell.row).Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(writeRow, 1)    
            writeRow = writeRow + 1             

        End If
    Next
```

Comment: "P" and 'R" are 2 columns apart

Comment: lol! Thanks. I've been using excel forever and I still hate letter'd columns. I have to sing the ABC's every danged time and then count on my fingers like a 5 year old.

Comment: you need `-2` , "P" is 2 columns on the left from "R". and loop only on relevant cells on column "R", not the entire column "R"

Comment: I have my own answer below :)

Comment: Oh! I see it now. Upvoted since you hit some things I didn't and beat me to the punch. :)

Comment: So, thank you, the internet is a great resource. I tried both of your two's code, but I'm getting a debug prompt. `If Cell.Value / Cell.Offset(, -2).Value > 0.021 Then` the system seems to not like that.

Comment: @George That is probably happening because you are dividing by zero at some point (which is common when doing this type of logic. I have added to my answer to fix that. If it's some other error bringing you into debug, then grab that error and paste it in here and we'll see if we can work around it. Writing VBA is 10% code writing and 80% debugging and 10% banging your head against the wall crying (especially when getting started)

Comment: @JNevill Ah, that would explain that, thanks. I wish the debug told me more that just the line that is problematic, cause now I'm getting a debug issue for `percentage = Cell.Value / Cell.Offset(, -2).Value` I believe it might be an issue with headers or text in the column?

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving before hitting the "Debug" button. They can be esoteric, but often times helpful in their own way.

Comment: @JNevill Sorry, forgot to include that, its a "Type mismatch" error.

Comment: By any chance do you have any non-numeric values in rows R or P? You can't divide a letter (or divide by a letter). Perhaps you need to be more restrictive then checking EVERY cell in `R:R`. IF you have headers then you might have to check that first like `If cell.row > 1 Then ... do the rest of this code`.

Comment: @JNevill So, I think this is the last issue but I'm getting a Compile Error: Next without For.

Comment: You probably have an `IF` statement that isn't closed with an `End If` or something like that?

Comment: @JNevill It would seem so, but If I close it, the does nothing. I have some blank rows and headers spread throughout `Sheet1` and I also changed your one line to `If Cell.Value <> "" And Cell.Value > 1 Then` though that hasn't helped the divide by 0 issue. I also got an error with your paste line the one time for some reason when I swapped the `> for <` out of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below:

```
Sub Filtration()

Dim Cell As Range
With Sheets(1)
    For Each Cell In .Range("R1:R" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row)            
        If Cell.Value / Cell.Offset(, -2).Value > 0.021 Then
            .Rows(Cell.Row).Copy
             Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Cell.Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                                        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False               
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```